# How to delete multiple files in a single commit using GitHub API with Go?

Tags: go, github, github-actions, github-pages, github-api

I'm working on a Go project where I need to programmatically delete multiple files in a single commit using the GitHub API.

I've been trying to create a new tree that reflects the state of the repository after the deletions and then create a commit from this tree. However, the commit appears on GitHub without any changes.

Here's a brief overview of the steps I'm taking:

1. Fetch the latest commit and get its tree.
2. Create a new list of tree entries, excluding the files I want to delete.
3. Create a new tree using these entries.
4. Create a new commit pointing to this tree.
5. Update the reference to point to the new commit.

Despite these steps, the commit doesn't show any changes. Here's a snippet of my code:

```golang
func DeleteFiles(ctx context.Context, files []string ) error {
    // Get the latest commit from the specified branch
    ref, _, err := g.Client.Git.GetRef(ctx, Owner, Repo, "refs/heads/"+Branch)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to get reference for the branch: %v", err)
    }

    // Get the commit's tree
    tree, _, err := g.Client.Git.GetTree(ctx, Owner, Repo, *ref.Object.SHA, true)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to get the tree for the commit: %v", err)
    }

    // Create a new tree from the base tree but without the files to delete
    entries := []github.TreeEntry{}
    for _, entry := range tree.Entries {
        keep := true
        for _, fileToDelete := range filesToDelete {
            if *entry.Path == fileToDelete {
                keep = false
                break
            }
        }
        if keep {
            entries = append(entries, entry)
        }
    }
    
    // Create a new tree with the updates
    newTree, _, err := g.Client.Git.CreateTree(ctx, Owner, Repo, "", entries)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to create new tree: %v", err)
    }

    // Create a new commit pointing to the new tree
    parent := []github.Commit{{SHA: ref.Object.SHA}}
    newCommit := &github.Commit{Message: github.String("Remove multiple files"), Tree: newTree, Parents: parent}
    commit, _, err := g.Client.Git.CreateCommit(ctx, Owner, Repo, newCommit)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to create commit: %v", err)
    }

    // Update the reference to point to the new commit
    ref.Object.SHA = commit.SHA
    _, _, err = g.Client.Git.UpdateRef(ctx, Owner, Repo, ref, false)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to update reference: %v ", err)
    }

    return nil
}
```

I tried both approach: rebuild the tree without the files, and also rebuild the tree giving the SHA value as empty string for the file I want to delete. To no avail :( any help is appreciated

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Github API; I assume you're using https://github.com/google/go-github? Another option is https://github.com/go-git/go-git which is just a Git tool. You can pull/push from Github and other platforms. For comparison, you can get the Worktree and call `wt.Remove(filename)` to accomplish that. Does the API have something like that?